# NI_Word.lvclass error following LabVIEW deployment

Tags: ms-word, labview

I sent an executable installer to a customer but he got the following response when he tried running it:

```
Possible reason(s):

LabVIEW: File not found. The file might be in a different location or deleted. Use the command prompt or the file explorer to verify that the path is correct.

Complete call chain:
     Get LV Class Default Value.vi
     NI_report.lvclass:New Report.vi
     Print Doc.vi
     Main.vi

LabVIEW attempted to load the class at this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\YYYYY\XXXXX.exe\1abvi3w\vi.lib\Utility\NIReport.llb\Word\NI_Word.lvclass
```

I have no problems on my PC running the program. It seems to an issue with the reporting toolkit. Any ideas how I can resolve it?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Microsoft Word? And is it even a programming-related question appropriate to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @CindyMeister The deployed program appears to have some integration with MS Word so it seems reasonable to discuss here. Also, I assume Stack Overflow's purview doesn't stop at programming. Programs must also be deployed right?

Comment: @CindyMeister The programming language is LabVIEW and the program uses activeX to speak with Microsoft Word in order to generate result files.  Might be better to remove the ms-word tag?

Answer (score 1):

The reporting toolkit is for the development side so if the problem were there, I'd expect that you would also experience it. NI has a writeup on what looks to be your issue. [Archived: Microsoft Word or Excel Not Launching From EXE Built With Report Generation Toolkit](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/C38CE3F30542D65B86256F0E00740DD8).

Answer (score 0):

4.5 years later and a search reveals my original question!

The answer in my case is to include both NI_Standard Report.lvclass & NI_Word.lvclass.

NI [answer](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372120A-01/lvrgthelp/rgt_stand_alone_apps/) the question but don't answer why it hasn't been automated into the process already!  Details as follows:

> Verify all files and VIs you use to build an application are in the
>   LabVIEW project. Add the following files to the LabVIEW project:
>   labview\vi.lib\Utility\NIReport.llb\Standard Report\NI_Standard
>   Report.lvclass if the application uses standard reports.
>   labview\vi.lib\Utility\NIReport.llb\Word\NI_Word.lvclass if the
>   application uses Microsoft Word.
>   labview\vi.lib\Utility\NIReport.llb\Excel\NI_Excel.lvclass if the
>   application uses Microsoft Excel.
>
> From the Source Files page of the Application Properties or Shared
>   Library Properties dialog box, navigate to and select the class files
>   you added to the project. Click the right arrow button next to the
>   Always Included list to add the class files to the application.
>
> If the application you are building contains the MS Office Report
>   Express VI, you must add any Microsoft Word or Microsoft Excel
>   templates that you use to the LabVIEW project and to the application.
>   From the Source Files page, select the template you use and click the
>   right arrow button next to the Always Included list to add the
>   template file to the application.
>
> For example, if you are using the basic Excel template with the MS
>   Office Report Express VI, add MSOffice_RGT_Template.xlt to the LabVIEW
>   project and the application. The basic template files are located in
>   the labview\templates\Report directory.Note  The default custom
>   destination for templates is a data subdirectory of the destination
>   directory. Do not change the custom destination for the templates you
>   add. If the application you are building contains the Word Add New
>   Document VI, ensure that the version of Microsoft Office installed on
>   the target computer is compatible with the application. Applications
>   containing the Word Add New Document VI that you build on a computer
>   with Office XP can run only on target computers that also have Office
>   XP. Applications containing the Word Add New Document VI that you
>   build on a computer with Office 2003 or 2007 can run only on target
>   computers with either Office 2003 or Office 2007.

Once both classes are included there are no issues.